# How to compose a Java file path

Tags: java, file, path

How do I compose a Java File Path?
I tried a lot but it didn't work.

```
package src;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException
public class ScanText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File fileName = new File("nativelog.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        while(inFile.hasNext()){
            if(inFile.nextLine().equals("H")){
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

My file is located on my desktop. I also tried: " C:\Desktop\nativelog.txt " but that didn't work at all. Could you help me with this?

Comment: did you escape \ in that path

Comment: It is easier to use forward slashes instead of backslashes in paths.

Comment: What do you mean by "compose" exactly? It is unclear what you want to do

Comment: Will it work if I change it to C:/Dekstop/nativelog.txt ?

Comment: Why don't you use JSR 203 instead of `File`? Hint: `Paths.get()`; and `Path` has nice methods such as `resolve()` etc

Comment: I actually meant "putting together"

Comment: Could you help me a little bit, this is all new for me

Comment: First of all, you can use forward slashes in Java programs, even when using it in a Windows environment. If you use backward slashes in a string constant, you have to escape it. Example: "C:\\Desktop\\nativelog.txt". Second, you are accessing a file in the _current directory_ with `new File("nativelog.txt");`. This is ok if the file is located in that current directory. If not, you will get an exception, which leads us to point 3: You said, "that didn't work at all", but you did not specify what that means. Please post any error and what else you think might help us to help you.

Comment: I found my fault. The problem was with the slashes. It has to be:

Comment: C:/Users/(user)/Desktop/nativelog.txt/

Comment: It doesn't *have to* be `/`. ``\`` should be also fine but since it is special character in String (it can be used to create other characters like `\n` or `\u0123`) we need to escape it with another ``\`` which means that to create ``\`` literal we need to write it as `"\\"`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write the path like:

```
  C:\\Desktop\\nativelog.txt
```

Or like:

```
 C:/Desktop/nativelog.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.nio.file.Paths (since Java 1.7) at this form:

```
Paths.get("c:", "desktop", "nativelog.txt").toString();
```

Comment: That will need to be "c:" so that it be recognized as a root; "c" will only be a directory named "c" in the current process' context

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\Desktop\\nativelog.txt";
path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regex syntax and ``\`` is special in regex. Either use `replaceAll("\\\\","/")` or change your method to `replace` (that would be probably less confusing).

Comment: @Pshemo Did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, that could be handy in another program I'm writing. Also thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear.

If you want the absolute path of a path you get as an argument you can just do:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("nativelog.txt").toAbsolutePath();
```